# How to get comma separated values from the string in php

Tags: php

I have a string `$employee="Mr vinay HS,engineer,Bangalore";`. i want to store Mr vinay H S in `$name` ,engineer in `$job` and Bangalore in `$location`. how to do this

Comment: Will there always be a comma splitting the fields? Reliably? There will be no `engineer, developer, and enterpreneur` spoiling the comma order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `list` function to take the exploded array into 3 variables

```
list($name, $job, $location) = explode(',', $employee);
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$record = explode(",",$employee);
$name = $record[0];
$job = $record[1];
$location = $record[2];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list($name,$job,$location) = explode(',',$employee);
```

Note: this will obviously only work if the string is in the format you specified. If you have any extra commas, or too few, then you'll have problems.

It's also worth pointing out that PHP has dedicated functions for handling CSV formatted data.

See the manual page for [str_getcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) for more info.

While `explode()` is the quickest and easiest way to do it, using `str_getcsv()` rather than simple `explode()` will allow you to handle input more complex input, eg containing quoted strings, etc.

Answer (score 3):

explode will do just that I guess

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Any more help on this would suffer from givemethecode-ism, so I leave you to it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
list($name,$job,$location) = explode(',',$employee);
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following should work:

```
//The employee name
$employee= "Mr vinay HS,engineer,Bangalore";

//Breaks each portion of the employee's name up
list($name, $job, $location) = explode(',',$employee);

//Outputs the employee's credentials
echo "Name: $name; Job: $job; Location: $location";
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use another function to do that - http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

```
list($name,$job,$location) = str_getcsv($employee);
```

Comment: +1 for str_getcsv() rather than explode()... because it will work with __Mr vinay HS,"engineer, developer, and enterpreneur",Bangalore__

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [list()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) functions:

```
list($name, $job, $location) = explode(",", $employee);
```